# Should I re-install Windows 10 on my failing hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, ubuntu-18.04, read-only, hard-drive-failure

I have dual-boot but i am unable to boot into windows. I booted into Ubuntu and it showed my hard disk is failing soon. The other partitions are now read-only. Would re-installing Windows 10 fix some of the drive issues and allow me to use it for maybe 6 more months?  What's the best way to backup data from a failing read-only hard disk?

Comment: Get your data off ASAP.  Don't attempt to continue to use it unless you don't care one bit about your data.

Comment: If you want to re-use the disk you could try to diagnose type and extension of the fault and re-partition it accordingly. I would only trust it as swap space, tough.

Comment: "hi, my car has a 90% chance to explode any moment when turned on. should i drive with it to my holiday vacation before calling an on-site repair service? i mean the trunk is still working ..."

Comment: @NumLock it depends on how expensive the repair is, if the repair cost 1 million dollars and there is a 10% chance it won't explode, I would take the bet unless by explode you mean I would have a 90% chance of dying. I think the moral of the story here is an SSD large enough to install windows cost $20 or less.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Would re-installing Windows 10 fix some of the drive issues?

**Warning**: Do not write to a failing hard drive as this makes it more likely to fail sooner.

> What's the best way to backup data from a failing read-only hard disk?

Please read [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device), which is our canonical question for data recovery.

The answers there give detailed instructions for various different scenarios.

Comment: I couldn't find any help for my scenario which is to transfer data from internal hdd to the replacement internal hdd. I don't have an external HDD and can't afford one at present. Would a "usb drive adapter" be any helpful?

Comment: That should do as a temp measure

Answer (score 2):

*It showed my hard disk is failing soon.*

No, I do not think so at all. Windows 10 does not repair hardware like this. So I suggest you replace the hard drive now. I think you will find hard drives to be reasonably priced

Answer (score 0):

**You should not install Windows on any hard drive.**

If you told me your hard drive was brand new I would still suggest getting rid of it (as an OS drive) unless it was the year 2007.

It is the year 2019, soon it will be the year 2020. An SSD large enough to install any version of windows cost 20 USD brand new (not on sale).

A hard drives only purpose is to store large files you want to lose. If you store Terabytes then yes a Hard Drive will be cheaper, but it's not as cheap as you think, because you need at least 2 or 3 to have the reliability of any SSD so the cost/return is diminishing rapidly.

The amount of time you will waste in extended loading times and inevitable data recovery will well exceed the $20 USD of a brand new SSD.

Checklist

1. You do not care if you lose all of your data.
2. You do not care if you have to often wait unnecessarily for your computer to load and have decreased performance in many common operations.
3. You would rather waste hours of time rather than spend $20.

If you say yes to all three then you definitely should re-install Windows 10 on your failing hard drive. I recommend using it to store large files you do not care about losing or perhaps giving it to your worst enemy to install his OS on.

Comment: You shouldn't thumbs down my answer just because you have a hard drive!

Comment: I think your answer is a bit tangential to what I asked about. I wanted to know what's the worst that could happen if I install any os on my failing hard disk. I was looking for also some hail mary trick that would prevent me from getting a new drive. My laptop is quite old, i5-2430M. Getting a SSD for it isn't really worth it. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: @sinisteraadi you can get a brand new SSD for $16 large enough to install any OS, how is that not worth it?